# jest- elasticsearch configuration with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have tried to create a CRUD app with spring and elasticsearch(aws instance). But getting some
datasouce issues.
I am facing some problem in configuring elasticsearch with spring.
Here is my configuration file
JestClientService

```
@Service
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = 
"com.mayank.crudelastic.repository")

public class JestClientService implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     System.out.println("setting up connection with jest");
     JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
        factory.setHttpClientConfig(
          new HttpClientConfig.Builder("elasticSearch AWS Instance conncetion link")
            .multiThreaded(true)
            .defaultMaxTotalConnectionPerRoute(2)
            .maxTotalConnection(10)
            .build());
        return factory.getObject();

}
```

And my application.properties file

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
```

UserEntity.java file

```
@Document(indexName="crud-user",shards=2)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;
    
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int age;
}
```

when i run the application this error comes up

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Hope you understood the problem, If there are any suggestion please reply

Comment: Please add your db credentials to application.properties.  Please add these , 1.spring.datasource.url 2.spring.datasource.username 3. spring.datasource.password

Comment: Can you use RestHighLevelClient instead of Jest?

Comment: @Gopikrishna I want to store data in elasticsearch indices only , not in local database. that's why i did not provided db credentials

Comment: Then you should remove your database accessing dependencies in your Pom.xml, because if dependencies like JPA  (for example) exists, they try to fetch the database url for db connection. If they don't find those properties you will get this error.